# How to import images with custom path in an iOS library that is consuming a React Native bundle?

Tags: ios, react-native

I have an iOS library that consumes a React Native bundle. This bundle includes some screens and code written in JavaScript. The thing is that React Native is not able to pick up the images.

For example, the bundle is looking for a specific path to the images `src/theme/images`.

When the React screen loads it says it cannot find the images because the images are getting imported directly into the image bundle of the native ios project and the custom path is not preserved.

I tried declaring the custom path inside the podspec but didn't work.

Any ideas?